# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 23

Tags: python, pandas, csv, stock, parse-error

I want to compile a list of the stocks that fit the criteria I set. I am looking at companies that have a market cap between $150,000 and $10,000,000 (in millions). When running the code below I am getting an error. I want to know what exactly I am doing wrong

'''
import yfinance as yf, pandas as pd, shutil, os, time, glob, smtplib, ssl
from get_all_tickers import get_tickers as gt

tickers = gt.get_tickers_filtered(mktcap_min=150000, mktcap_max=10000000)

print("The amount of stocks chosen to observe: " + str(len(tickers)))

'''

Additional Data:

runfile('A:/Misc Financial Docs/stocks_data/OBV_Email.py', wdir='A:/Misc Financial Docs/stocks_data')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "A:\Misc Financial Docs\stocks_data\OBV_Email.py", line 13, in 
tickers = gt.get_tickers_filtered(mktcap_min=150000, mktcap_max=10000000)

File "c:\users\aos82\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\get_all_tickers\get_tickers.py", line 84, in get_tickers_filtered
tickers_list.extend(__exchange2list_filtered(exchange, mktcap_min=mktcap_min, mktcap_max=mktcap_max, sectors=sectors))

File "c:\users\aos82\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\get_all_tickers\get_tickers.py", line 145, in __exchange2list_filtered
df = __exchange2df(exchange)

File "c:\users\aos82\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\get_all_tickers\get_tickers.py", line 134, in __exchange2df
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",")

File "c:\users\aos82\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 605, in read_csv
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File "c:\users\aos82\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 463, in _read
return parser.read(nrows)

File "c:\users\aos82\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1052, in read
index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)

File "c:\users\aos82\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2056, in read
data = self._reader.read(nrows)

File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 756, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read

File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 771, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory

File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 827, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows

File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 814, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows

File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1951, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 23, saw 4

Comment: Hello. Please 1) Type your question 2) Give example datas 3) Give reproducible example 4 ) Use triple quote for code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 2):

this appears to have to do with a new URL for the Nasdaq API. The authors have a ticket open here: https://github.com/shilewenuw/get_all_tickers/issues/12. Basically there's a new header that they use.

```
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'authority': 'api.nasdaq.com',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
    'origin': 'https://www.nasdaq.com',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://www.nasdaq.com/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

params = (
    ('tableonly', 'true'),
    ('limit', '25'),
    ('offset', '0'),
    ('download', 'true'),
)

r = requests.get('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks', headers=headers, params=params)`
data = r.json()['data']
df = pd.DataFrame(data['rows'], columns=data['headers'])
```

Also in the link above, there's a contributor that provides a full replacement for the get_tickers.py file that I used and it works for me.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore.